# a qualitative study of $y'=x(1+{1\over y})$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have as initial date $y(0)=\alpha$ for $y'=x(1+{1\over y})$ , the graph of the solution y(x) is under a parable. Can i use the comparison theorem?

Comment: If you mean $f,g\in C^1([x_0,X_0])$ and $f(x_0) < g(x_0)$, $f'(x) < g'(x) \quad\forall x_0 \le x \le X_0 \Rightarrow f(x) < g(x) \ \forall x_0\le x\le X_0$, yes.

Comment: Note that this equation is separable, and can be integrated without too much trouble.

Comment: @Travis ...Leading to an *implicit* formula for $y(x)$. Starting from this, one needs more work to deduce the behaviour of $y(x)$.

Comment: @Did Yes, of course, I did not mean to claim that the observation somehow resolves OP's question altogether, but rather that it offers another tack on the problem unavailable for some more complicated problems of this type.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, **one assumes that $y(0)=\alpha$ is positive**.

Then $y'(x)\geqslant0$ for every $x\geqslant0$ hence the function $x\mapsto y(x)$ is nonnegative and nondecreasing on $x\geqslant0$, in particular $y(x)\geqslant\alpha$ hence $y'(x)\leqslant(1+\alpha^{-1})x$.

Integrating this on $[0,x]$ yields $y(x)\leqslant\frac12(1+\alpha^{-1})x^2+\alpha$ for every $x\geqslant0$, as desired.

Likewise, $y'(x)\geqslant x$ for every $x\geqslant0$ hence $y(x)\geqslant\frac12x^2+\alpha$ for every $x\geqslant0$, which proves that indeed, $y(x)=\Theta(x^2)$ when $x\to+\infty$.